# Python Flask Render Field macro take arguments jinja2

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I am trying make a macro that takes in arguments and adds the elements to the form field. This is my current code.

```
      {% macro render_field(field,class,**custom) %}
  <div class="form-group">
    {% if field.name != "submit" %}
    {{ field.label }}
    {% endif %}



      {{ field(class="form-control %s" % class , custom ) }}
  </div>
  {% endmacro %}


{{ render_field(form.reciver_name,"test","placeholder = a") }}
```

I just dont know how to accept multiple arguments and dont understand **kwargs very well

I get this error TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'name', got '**'

Comment: What problem are you encountering with your code?  Can you provide an example of what you expect to happen?

Comment: So when i do do this {{ render_field(form.reciver_name,"test","placeholder = a") }} I want it to output <input class="form-control test" id="reciver_name" name="reciver_name" placeholder="a" type="text" value="">

Comment: You may have a problem using a reserved keyword, in this case `class`, as the name of an argument. WTForms handles this through an argument named `class_`. Try using that instead.

Comment: that is not where the problem is. I dont think that is the case but i changed the parameter name just in case

Answer (score 2):

Jinja macros aren't exactly the same as defining a python function.  See here: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#macros

So I don't think you need the `**custom` in your macro definition.  Also, when you are calling the macro, the third argument is not a keyword argument.  It is the literal string `"placeholder = a"`.

You can try call the macro like this:

```
{{ render_field(form.reciver_name, "test", placeholder="a") }}
```

Jinja should put the placeholder keyword arg in the `kwargs` special variable.  I'm not very familiar with flask-wtforms, but you should be able to use this `kwargs` variable in the `field(...)` function call.

For future reference:  `kwargs` needs to be accessed at least once in the macro for it to accept any keyword arguments.  See linked duplicate question for more details.

Comment: When I try this "TypeError: macro 'render_field' takes no keyword argument 'placeholder'" but thankyou for the tip of kwargs as a special variable

Comment: You need to actually use `**kwargs` in the `render_field` call. Jinja macros automagically accept arbitrary kwargs if you use `kwargs` inside the macro. See http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#macros